# How can I change URL of 'Add new comment' link on teaser?

Tags: comments, navigation, nodes

Currently, I have a list of teasers and they have a comment count and an 'Add new comment' link.

That link goes to a dedicated comment page with a URL of the form "/comment/reply/19#comment-form".

However, I want it to go to the actual node which has the comment form at the bottom (eg. "/node/19#comment-form").

Maybe this can be done is the template.php or some other way. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the admin page for your content type

> /admin/structure/types/manage/page

and check `Show reply form on the same page as comments` under `Comment settings`.

If you look at [comment_node_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/comment_node_view/7) in the comment module, you can see where the comment link is added to teasers.

```
    if (user_access('post comments')) {
      $links['comment-add'] = array(
        'title' => t('Add new comment'),
        'href' => "comment/reply/$node->nid",
        'attributes' => array('title' => t('Add a new comment to this page.')),
        'fragment' => 'comment-form',
      );
    }
```

To alter the link you can use [hook_node_view_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7) in your module.

```
function MODULE_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  $node = $build['#node'];
  if (isset($build['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add'])) {
    // Alter the 'Add new comment' link.
    $build['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']['href'] = "node/$node->nid";
    // Fragment is the '#comment-form' part of the url.
    $build['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']['fragment'] = 'comment-form';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I've already got the comment form showing on the node page. I want the 'Add New Comment' link on the teaser to go to that node page (and not the dedicated Comment page it currently does go to).

Comment: I added a description how to alter the `Add new comment` link.

Comment: Thank you so much Marcus. This did exactly what I wanted. I had to put single quotes around the #node on the second line, so the line was:
`$node = $build['#node'];`
but otherwise it worked wonderfully, thank you.

Comment: @MarcusAschan this works great, but would you happen to know how to add HTML to the 'title' (that on default renders 'Add new comment')? I'm trying to add a FontAwesome icon (<i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i>) before this and it's currently showing up as plain text.

Comment: @WebMW you should be able to render HTML by adding `$build['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']['html'] = TRUE;`. You can check the documentation for [theme_links](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_links/7.x) for more options.

Comment: @MarcusAschan, you are a savior! I can't express how many hours were put into not only asking this question to Drupal Support on IRC, but on both Stack Exchange & Stack Overflow. THANK YOU! I'd like you to have the credit for those if you could provide your answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246936/why-is-html-rendering-as-plain-text-in-a-simple-title-alteration & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46477873/why-is-html-rendering-as-plain-text-in-a-simple-title-alteration

Comment: @WebMW glad I could help! :) I answered you two questions.