# Why is HTML rendering as Plain Text in a simple 'title' alteration?

Tags: views, theming

I have been able to change each node's Comment Link 'title' text (that on default renders 'Add new comment') with the below code, but if I add HTML, it renders as plain text. I'm trying to add a FontAwesome icon before this text `<i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

[image]

```
function MODULE_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  $node = $build['#node'];
  if (isset($build['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add'])) {
    $build['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']['title'] = '<i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Comment';
  }
}
```

All I have passed is a $build parameter, but I am unsure of whether or not this is the issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render HTML in links by setting the `html` option to `TRUE`.
Check [theme_links()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_links/7.x) to see all options.

For example

```
theme('links', array(
  'links' => array(
    'title' => '<span>Title</span>',
    'href' => 'node/1',
    'html' => FALSE, // default
  )
))
```

would result in the span tag being escaped, while

```
theme('links', array(
  'links' => array(
    'title' => '<span>Title</span>',
    'href' => 'node/1',
    'html' => TRUE,
  )
))
```

would render the span tag as html.

So in your case you need to add the following row.

```
$build['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']['html] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Titles do not support HTML markup.  This is AFAIK a security countermeasure.

There was an [HTML Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/html_title) module but it can no longer be downloaded because of unfixed security issues.

If you want to add an icon, you can add it to the form as `#markup` and then just adjust the placement as needed.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Could you please provide an example of how I can add HTML to the comment title as #markup?

Comment: @WebMV, put the string in `t()`. This creates a translatable markup, which is best practice in Drupal for all strings containing translatable strings and also solves your problem with escaping of html tags.

Comment: The t() function may be best practice but doesn't seem to make a difference. For now, I'm hacking the icon in with CSS:before & unicode... :(